# How to Integrate Yahoo API Search in web-Application using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to integrate yahoo search api in my web application in asp.net with C#.
I don't know how to call yahoo api.

Answer (score 1):

```
string AppId = "foo";
string Query = "stackoverflow";
int NumResults = 10;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string request = string.Format(
    "http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid={0}&query={1}&results={2}"
    , AppId
    , Query
    , NumResults);            
byte[] response = webClient.DownloadData(request);
string responseXML = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
Console.WriteLine(responseXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it still works, but I wrote a C# & VB.Net wrapper for this some years ago. Yahoo even included it in their sample code. You can download it from [my site](http://www.mgbrown.com/downloads.aspx). Basically you use XSD.Exe on the XML schema that you get from Yahoo's developer web site and then desearialize the result of your web request into the objects XSD.exe produces.